# Can't execute a transaction block while working with a database. Kotlin, Exposed

Tags: database, kotlin, transactions, kotlin-exposed

I am trying to send transactions to the Postgre database (the table exists) using the Exposed framework for Kotlin, but an error occurs that does not allow me to do this. The error appears on the line `SchemaUtils.create(tableTest)`

Source code:

```
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.id.IntIdTable
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.*
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.transaction

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val db = Database.connect("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testBase", driver = "org.postgresql.Driver", user = "user", password = "123")
    println("Database name: ${db.name}")
    transaction {
        addLogger(StdOutSqlLogger)
        SchemaUtils.create(tableTest)
        println("People: ${tableTest.selectAll()}")
    }
}

object tableTest: Table() {
    val id = integer("id")
    val name = text("name")
    val surname = text("surname")
    val height = integer("height")
    val phone = text("phone")

    override val primaryKey = PrimaryKey(id)
}
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at MainKt$main$1.invoke(main.kt:12)
    at MainKt$main$1.invoke(main.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt$inTopLevelTransaction$1.invoke(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:170)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt$inTopLevelTransaction$2.invoke(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:211)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.keepAndRestoreTransactionRefAfterRun(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:219)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.inTopLevelTransaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:210)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt$transaction$1.invoke(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:148)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.keepAndRestoreTransactionRefAfterRun(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:219)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:120)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:118)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction$default(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:117)
    at MainKt.main(main.kt:10)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: javaClass.`package` must not be null
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Table.<init>(Table.kt:306)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Table.<init>(Table.kt:303)
    at tableTest.<init>(main.kt:30)
    at tableTest.<clinit>(main.kt:30)
    ... 12 more
```

build.gradle.kts:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.0"
    application
}
group = "me.amd"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed", "exposed-core", "0.26.2")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed", "exposed-dao", "0.26.2")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed", "exposed-jdbc", "0.26.2")
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.16")
    implementation("org.slf4j", "slf4j-api", "1.7.25")
    implementation("org.slf4j", "slf4j-simple", "1.7.25")

    implementation("org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.30.1")
}
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>() {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
application {
    mainClassName = "MainKt"
}
```

Tried doing like this:

```
transaction {
    addLogger(StdOutSqlLogger)
    val schema = Schema("tableTest", authorization = "postgres", password = "123456")
    SchemaUtils.setSchema(schema)
    println("People: ${tableTest.selectAll()}")
}
```

but the error has moved to the line `println("People: ${tableTest.selectAll()}")`

I tried to send queries to SQLite — everything is the same

How to fix this error and still send a request to the database? I hope for your help!

Comment: Does adding a package statement above your import statements solve the problem?

Comment: @DanielJacob unfortunately this doesn't work. If I add package statement, Event Log shows: "class 'MainKt' not found"

Comment: That's a different error isn't it? Try to wrap your main method in a class like Class Main{} for example.

Comment: @DanielJacob Thank you! This is magic, the error is gone! But `addLogger(StdOutSqlLogger)` does not work and `println("People: $ {tableTest.selectAll ()}")` shows `People: org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Query@dc24521`

Comment: Glad it works! I have added my comment as an answer.

Comment: As for the error for the addLogger you need to share more info of the addLogger. The other error can be solved by using a Spring EL expression, since ${} only works on properties. What you are doing here is an expression and you want to use # for that.

Comment: @DanielJacob I noticed that addLogger does not work, because the program cannot access the table because the table name contains uppercase letters, and the query is created with the table name in lowercase. It works with tables with names in lowercase. I will try with Spring EL. Interestingly, "Getting started" on the official wiki uses $

Comment: I guess exposed has their own framework for resolving properties, so $ should be fine then.

Comment: It's nothing about Exposed but Kotlin [string templates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#using-string-templates). 

When you call `tableTest.selectAll()` you just prepare Query instance and don't execute the query. You can use `println("People: $ {tableTest.selectAll().map { it[tableTest.name}}")` to print all names. And then you also will see raw SQL from the logger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a package statement above your import statements. Furthermore, add your main method in a class.